# How can I solve Angular module import problem?

Tags: angular, angular9

**It's working**

```
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button'
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu'
```

**Not Working**

```
import { MatButtonModule,MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material'
```

Why do you think it would be?

Comment: How are you saying it is not working do you get any errors?? If so edit the question with relevant details..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan  I think it makes no sense. Error Message:  ERROR in src/app/materials/materials.module.ts:3:46 - error TS2306: File '......../Projects/aviyiva/node_modules/@angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a module.
    
    3 import { MatButtonModule,MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material'

Comment: You can look at the example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-starter-76hgza it is working fine only..

Comment: You might have upgraded your angular cli version to 9!

Comment: @SunnyParekh  yes. Angular CLI: 9.0.5 Node: 13.10.1 .

Comment: Yes with Angular 9, you will have to import each component separately. This is a major change they introduced.

Comment: @SunnyParekh Thank You. I never loved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's no longer supported in Angular's 9th version.

> Components can no longer be imported through "@angular/material". Use
>   the individual secondary entry-points, such as
>   @angular/material/button.

**Source**: [git issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17503) and [changelog](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#material-6)